# Actor events do not work when instantiating it before calling stage.addActor(actor) libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I am newber
Actor events do not work when instantiating it before calling stage.addActor(actor). It works when i Actor events do not work when instantiating it before calling stage.addActor(actor). It works when I do the opposite.
Where am i fail?

I am newber
Actor events do not work when instantiating it before calling stage.addActor(actor). It works when i Actor events do not work when instantiating it before calling stage.addActor(actor). It works when I do the opposite.
Where am i fail?